# Converting html text into PHP

Tags: php, html

I am populating a table with objects received from a JSON array generated by a remote PHP file:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.material_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.service_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.ordered}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.pending}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.unit}}></td>
                    <td>{{data.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.cost}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.net}}</td>

                    <td><a href="edit_po_item.php?id={{data.id_po}}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Depending on the received values I need to make some design changes, for example, if `{{data.pending}}` is an integer between 1 and 5 I want to change the cell background color.

How can I convert the text value from `{{data.unit}}` to a variable that would let me set conditions to change the layout of the table?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in CSS and not in PHP, personally...

Change:

```
<td>{{data.pending}}</td>
```

To:

```
<td data-pending-code='{{data.pending}}'>{{data.pending}}</td>
```

and now you can do stuff like:

```
<style>
td[data-pending-code="1"] { background: red; }
td[data-pending-code="2"] { background: blue; }
td[data-pending-code="3"] { background: green; }
td[data-pending-code="4"] { background: yellow; }
td[data-pending-code="5"] { background: purple; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, I will test it, but this solution implies to declare all possible values one by one, and I would prefer to have the chance to define filters.

Answer (score 1):

you could force the conversion to a number with `{{data.pending*1}}` and then check for your design.
[Here's a fiddle showing conversion](https://jsfiddle.net/wb7g94q0/)